# In Power BI, is there a way to repoint the data source while keeping all the field formatting and calculated columns in the visuals?

Tags: powerbi

I have a PBI that I set up initially from a CSV file on my desk top to test functionality while waiting for the DB connection.  I've finally gotten the connection but I don't see how I can retain all the changes and calculated columns I put in to the report with the CSV file.  Any ideas or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 0):

Open your report and go to `File` -> `Options and settings` -> `Data source settings`:

[image]

There make sure `Data sources in current file` is selected and click on `Change Source` button.